# HTML - How to properly mark a phrase

Tags: html, semantics

The `<blockquote>` tag demand a `cite` external source, but what if the only source is the name of the phrase author?

The `<cite>` tag defines the name of a work (e.g. a book, a song, a movie, a TV show, a painting, a sculpture, etc.), so it's no suitable to what I need.

There is a better way to mark a phrase, with your author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<blockquote>` doesn't *demand* a `cite`, it's optional. Don't overthink it. `<blockquote>` without `cite` is what you're looking for.